# Determine Which Application Server our application is deployed to?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, jboss, oc4j

Our J2EE Application  is deployed to JBoss and sometimes to OC4J .
 Can I know which one is being used?
 I hope there is a method returning the container information on runtime.

Comment: What is the problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest thing I can think of is to look through the system properties at runtime, since both servers are almost certainly going to define their own. For example, JBoss 4 defines the `jboss.server.dir` system property. Check to see if that property exists, and if it does, then you can assume you're running under that server. OC4J will have something similar.

Alternatively, try reflectively loading a class that is part of the server's infrastructure (e.g. `org.jboss.Version` in JBoss 4). If it exists, you know what server you're on.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this out by [`ServletContext#getServerInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServerInfo%28%29).

Comment: Curious... I suspect that'll return the name of the servlet container, rather than the app server, but it may be enough.

Comment: Depends on the appserver. For example JBoss 4.2.x and newer do return "JBoss", but the older versions used to return "Apache Tomcat".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) is what you are going to need to use.  Both containers likely expose details about themselves as MBeans.  Here is some [Oracle documentation on JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/oc4j/1003/how_to/how-to-simplembeans/doc/readme.html) and [JBoss documentation](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=214).

Answer (score 0):

Change to `System.getProperty("jboss.home.dir")`