# How can I determine the J2ee application server type and version?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, jmx

I need to detect information about the Application Server my EJBs are running in.
The System.properties contain a lot of information about Java and the Operating system, but I need to know what type of application server and if possible even the version.

Is there a way to get this information in an application independent way (JMX maybe) ?
Alternatively, is there a WebSphere specific way of getting this information ?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745836/determine-which-application-server-our-application-is-deployed-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look through the [WAS MBeans](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/mbeandocs/index.html) that are available. It looks like the [Server MBean](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/mbeandocs/Server.html) may have some of the info you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could try ServletContext.getServerInfo(), though I'm not sure what specific information WebSphere will give you with that. On Tomcat I get the string e.g. "Apache Tomcat/6.0.16"

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee you are allowed to check system properties.

What is the problem you need to solve?