# How to determine type of Application Server an application is running on?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Our EJB3 application can run on top of Oracle AS or JBoss AS. Is there a way to find out type of AS during runtime?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745836/determine-which-application-server-our-application-is-deployed-to and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117704/how-can-i-determine-the-j2ee-application-server-type-and-version

Comment: Our application is not a web application

Comment: I didn't say it was. Neither of those duplicates is specific to webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the concrete type of object at runtime using reflection, e.g. the `EJBContext` that is injected by the app. server.

Comment: Thanks!!

In jboss it returns:
org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessSessionContextImpl

Comment: disadvantage may be that you need some `@EJB class Ejb { @Inject EJBContext ejbCtx; }` to make it work. so the system properties approach in our scenario seemed more fitting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41528206/1915920

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to check for an app-server specific value in System properties.

```
// EXAMPLE:
if (System.getProperty("catalina.base") != null) {
  // Using Tomcat
  ...
else if (System.getProperty("jboss.server.name") != null) {
  // Using JBoss
  ...
else if (System.getProperty("was.install.root") != null) {
  // Using WebSphere
  ...
```